# Creating a scrollable area inside a div that fills the parent container?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create something like the following:

[image]

Inside of a container, I want to have a fixed sized header, and then a scrollable div below it that fills all of the remaining space. I seem to be going about this wrong, as when I try setting the scrollable div's height to `100%`, it pops out of the containers body.

Here's what i've come up with so far:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="top-part">
        Hello!
    </div>

    <div class="scrollable-bottom">
        <h1>Content</h1><h1>Content</h1><h1>Content</h1><h1>Content</h1><h1>Content</h1><h1>Content</h1><h1>Content</h1><h1>Content</h1><h1>Content</h1><h1>Content</h1><h1>Content</h1><h1>Content</h1><h1>Content</h1
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    border: 1px solid #cacaca;
}

.top-part {
    width: 100%; 
    height: 70px;
    border: 1px solid #cacaca;
}

.scrollable-bottom {
    height: 100%; 
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 247, 0.4);

}
```

If you checkout the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/o2307qup/1/), you'll see that the `scrollable-bottom` shoots outside of the `container`. I can't figure out why this is..

Doesn't the `height` property refer to the parent elements height? If so, then why isn't it being constrained?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`height: 100%;` means 100% of the elements parent height, so if parent height is 400px, child height is going to be 400px as well.

You can get away from calculating sizes of your `.scrollable-bottom` on your own with use of `calc()` function. [It's supported in modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc)

You can also get rid of magic numbers by changing box model behavior of `.top-part` and `.scrollable-bottom`, setting `box-sizing: border-box;` for `.top-part` and `.scrollable-bottom` 
It will change its behavior to contain paddings and borders inside the defined width/height of the box area instead of enlarging it by the padding and border width/height

This way, you no longer need to worry about changing `.scrollable-bottom` height/width whenever you add or remove padding or border to it or the `.top-part`

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #cacaca;
}
.top-part, 
.scrollable-bottom {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.top-part {
  width: 100%; 
  height: 70px;
  border: 1px solid #cacaca;
}

.scrollable-bottom {
  height: calc(100% - 70px); /* parent height - .top-part height */
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 247, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="top-part">
        Hello!
    </div>

    <div class="scrollable-bottom">
        <h1>Content</h1><h1>Content</h1><h1>Content</h1><h1>Content</h1><h1>Content</h1><h1>Content</h1><h1>Content</h1><h1>Content</h1><h1>Content</h1><h1>Content</h1><h1>Content</h1><h1>Content</h1><h1>Content</h1
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're absolutely correct. The 100% height refers to the full height of the container. But also note there is the top bar height that should be calculated here.

Giving it a negative top margin the same amount of the top bar should fix it, but it will hide a partial amount of the bottom content itself, that's why we add a top padding with the same amount of the height.

```css
*{
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    border: 1px solid #cacaca;
}

.top-part {
    width: 100%; 
    height: 70px;
    border: 1px solid #cacaca;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    background: white;
}

.scrollable-bottom {
    height: 100%; 
    overflow-y: scroll;
    padding-top: 70px;
    margin-top: -70px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 247, 0.4);
        
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="top-part">
        Hello!
    </div>
    
    <div class="scrollable-bottom">
        <h1>Content</h1><h1>Content</h1><h1>Content</h1><h1>Content</h1><h1>Content</h1><h1>Content</h1><h1>Content</h1><h1>Content</h1><h1>Content</h1><h1>Content</h1><h1>Content</h1><h1>Content</h1><h1>Content</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the scroll bar indicator/slider is partially hidden, which could cause accessibility issues if the content were long enough to cause the indicator icon to become short enough to be completely hidden.

Answer (score 0):

As your containers height is 400px and 70px height is covered by the header.
Just give `max-height:330px` to scrollable div. It will solve your problem. Here is the result http://jsfiddle.net/o2307qup/2/

There maybe some paddings, margins and borders that you might be playing with. So change the max-height according to them, if you are not seeing the perfect result. Also read the comment below of @Marc

Comment: You should set the max-height to 328px to take into account the height of the top part, which is 72px, 70px height + 2px for top/bottom borders.  You could also use height of 328px and get nearly the same result.  The difference would be critical if you had a background image or color to the scrollable area.